# Как запустить два скрипта одновременно? Python

Tags: python, база-данных

Делаю бота ВК на питоне. Я хочу сделать так что бы моя база данных автосохранялась каждые несколько секунд. Можно ли как то сделать так, что бы скрипт и работал как просто бот, и что бы бд сохранял.

Comment: Самый просто вариант сделайте функцию автосохранения и запихните ее в отдельный поток.

Comment: а как. Я новичок

Comment: модуль threading              https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/

Comment: Используйте многопоточность, что бы выполнить несколько задач одновременно
Ссылка на [статью с объяснением](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/python_threading_part1?utm_source=admitad&utm_medium=cpa&utm_campaign=admitad&utm_content=courses&utm_term=14/09/2017&partner_id=admitad&click_id=3d0eedd5a83cfdc664d6bb9d53e8e5a6&sub_id=442763)

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа простой пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каркас программы под поток на сохранение

```py
from threading import Thread


def save_db():
    # Ваша функция сохранения
    print("Save!")

def my_bot():
    pass

thread1 = Thread(target=save_db, args=(), daemon=True) # Создаем поток
thread1.start() # Запускаем.
my_bot() # Запускаем бота

# А тут весь остальной код..
print("Ваша программа...\n")
```

Comment: Стоп это так будет работать?
А я думал надо будет создавать две функции...

Comment: Можно создать две функции для сохранения и бота и запустить их двумя потоками тут уже зависит от ваших пожеланий. В данном примере  бота не обязательно засовывать в поток. Главное чтобы создание и запуск потоков были сделаны перед запуском бота.

Comment: спасибо большое