# 2 бота Telegram в одном скрипте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

нужно запустить 2 бота из одного скрипта(для загрузки на сервер), на компьютере в пайчарме для теста бота заупускал по отдельности 2 скрипта, сейчас при загрзуке на сервер возникла проблема, нужно из 1 скрипта запускать сразу 2 ботов, каким образом это можно реализовать?

`main.py` - запуск первого бота(бот клиента)
`main_admin.py` - запуск второго бота(для админа)
`main_client_admin.py` - попытка запуска 2 файлов из 1 скрипта

**main.py**

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
from create_bot import dp
from handlers import client
from data_base import sqlite_db


def start_client_bot():
    print("Бот на зв'зку")
    sqlite_db.sql_start()

    client.register_handlers_client(dp)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


start_client_bot()
```

**main_admin.py**

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
from create_bot_admin import dp_admin
from handlers import admin


def start_admin_bot():
    admin.register_handlers_admin(dp_admin)
    executor.start_polling(dp_admin, skip_updates=True)


start_admin_bot()
```

**main_client_admin.py**

```
import subprocess


subprocess.Popen('main.py')
subprocess.Popen('main_admin.py')
```

Comment: Это становиться возможным при использовании отдельного потока. Иначе второй бот просто не запустится, т.к. пулинг работает вечно, до следующей строки дело не дойдет ): мб это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221159/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-python

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: увы не помогло, работает только 1 из 2 ботов, потом после завершения работы первого бота запускается второй